# Search of String value having special character in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have one table emp in MySQL database having column as name. In that name column, the value is 'abc\xyz'. I want to search this value. I have tried using following query:

```
select * from emp where name like 'abc\xyz';
```

Also i have tried

```
select * from emp where name like 'abc\xyz' escape '\\';
```

But i did not found any output. Could you please help me in finding such strings? Such strings can have special character at any location.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tried `WHERE name = 'abc\\xyz'`?

Comment: It's working. But what if I want to search a string using wildcard characters? If my string is like 1111abc\xyz2222 and I am trying to match using abc\xyz or say using like?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Reminds me of this ~ http://art.penny-arcade.com/photos/528500159_EHxUb-XL-2.jpg

Answer (score 2):

You may try like this:

```
select * from emp
where empname like '%abc\\\\xyz%'
```

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11c39/1)**

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html):

> Because MySQL uses C escape syntax in strings (for example, “\n” to represent a newline character), you must double any “\” that you use in LIKE strings. For example, to search for “\n”, specify it as “\\n”. **To search for “\”, specify it as “\\\\”; this is because the backslashes are stripped once by the parser and again when the pattern match is made, leaving a single backslash to be matched against.**

Comment: I think some of your doco text got escaped by StackOverflow :) Also, you don't need the `ESCAPE` character because you aren't using any literal `%` or `_`

Comment: @AasifSolkar I had to fix some formatting in this post. To search for a literal "\" in a `LIKE` match, you have to use 4 backslashes, eg `abc\\\\xyz`

Comment: @AasifSolkar:- I have updated my answer. Please check!

Comment: @R.T. - it's working but what if you don't know the actual position of special character in column value?

Comment: @AasifSolkar:- I am not sure about your question but if you want to check for a string containing slash then you can simple use `%\\\\%` like http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11c39/2

Comment: @AasifSolkar:- Or may be this to check slash for different location:- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11c39/3

Comment: I have tried :

select * from emp where replace(name,'\\','') like replace(str_to_check,'\\','');

And it's working because I'm calling this query from java and passing value 'str_to_check' from java code.

Comment: @AasifSolkar:- You are welcome. And do accept the answer if that helped you. On side note:- Do add the relevant tags and how you are using the code so  that it helps us to undertsand your specific problem. happy coding.

Comment: @R.T. : Sure :-) [tag:mysql]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT REPLACE(text,'\\','') FROM tbl
```

You can use REPLACE to remove some special chars :)

Comment: This has the problem of corrupting the results. Not recommended

Comment: It is not the best way but it can replace the special chars

Comment: We can use replace function but it's showing error if my special character is at starting or ending location. For e.g. I have tried

select * from emp where replace(name,'\\','') like replace('\xyz\abc\','\\','');

But it gives error as 

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\\','')' at line 1

Comment: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\\','')' at line 1"

Comment: Sorry but i try it in phpmyadmin and navicat for mysql
And i got no errors

Comment: Can you please try on MySQL admin or MySQL query browser?

Comment: I try it in PHPMYADMIN Query Browser

What tools did you use?

Comment: @ShenShen : I'm using MySQL query browser and MySQL Administrator.

Comment: Try this
SELECT REPLACE(text,'\\\','') FROM tbl

Comment: @ShenShen : Not required to use '\\\'. It can be achieved by using only two slash like

SELECT REPLACE(text,'\\','') FROM tbl;

Comment: I am trying it with java

Comment: `REPLACE(text,'\\','')` is *not at all* the answer to this question; beyond that, your SQL syntax makes no sense in relation to the actual query being run. The actual answer was posted an hour before yours. You don't seem to understand escaping. He needs to **add** slashes to his query. Not remove them.